# Velocity Unable To find Resources

Tags: apache, maven, velocity

This question is already asked but i am trying the same thing that is in accepted answer

```
protected static final String RESOURCE_LOADER = classpath.resource.loader.class";    

static {
    System.out.println("Velocity Initialization Started");
    velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
    velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
    velocityEngine.setProperty(RESOURCE_LOADER,ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
    try {
        velocityEngine.init();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        LOG.error("Failed to load velocity templates e={}", e); 
    }
}
```

my velocity file is in

```
src/main/resources/velocity/templates/command/name.vm
```

i am getting templates by following command

```
template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("velocity/templates/command/GenericState.vm");
```

It works locally but when bundled in jar it does not work , I have examined the jar it consist of velocity folder

i am using velocity to generated java code

I am having maven project setup and maven is creating jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way it should work.

```
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class,file");
    velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "VELLOGGER");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
    velocityEngine.init();
```

Comment: and give the complete path for template like template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("velocity/templates/command/GenericState.vm");

Comment: have you added my code with your code ? Try in this way `/velocityEngine.getTemplate("velocity/templates/command/Gener‌​icState.vm");` or `../`before velocity and check .

Comment: Yeah It worked !! But Later i modified to the previous code it also started working , Verifying what caused the issue earlier, Accepting the solution as it is also correct solution.