# ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'index.vm' in any resource loader

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to create a simple java project with Velocity Templates and I keep getting error  -

```
ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'index.vm' in any resource loader.
```

index.vm exists along with the Class file. I have tried couple of other options but nothing is working.

I have looked the following resources:

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html

[Velocity Unable To find Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451069/velocity-unable-to-find-resources)

Class file:

```
        VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class, file");
        velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class",
       "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("\\templates\\index.vm");

        VelocityContext vContext = new VelocityContext();
        velocityEngine.init();

        vContext.put("name", "World");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        t.merge(vContext, writer);

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

I tried adding following properties to velocity context but it doesnt work.

```
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class,file");
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "VELLOGGER");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
```

**UPDATE 1:** After changing the path I was able to run it successfully inside Ec lipse but after exporting the project as runnable jar or maven shaded jar, I still get the same error.
Here is the stack trace:

```
SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource '\templates\index.vm' in any resource loader.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think that all you need to do is to move the line:

```
Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("index.vm");
```

further down, after velocity engine initialization.

If it still doesn't work, where is your `index.vm` located?

If it's a file, then you are missing something like:

```
velocityEngine.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", "/some/path/");
```

If it's a resource in the classpath, you may be lacking a `/` in front of `index.vm`:

Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate('/index.vm')

Comment: After changing the path and adding those 4 properties I was able to run in eclipse but while executing jar it's still gives the same error.

Comment: @NaiveCoder You didn't answer my question: where is the template? Inside the jar or in the file system?

Comment: @ Claude Brisson, it's in the resources folder (resouces/templates/index.vm) in maven project. Template is not in jar file. But when exported the maven project as jar and trying to execute the jar, it gives error "Resoruce not found"

Comment: @NaiveCoder You do not really answer my question. What do you intend to do? Have the template in the jar? If so, you're maybe missing the proper `<resources>` section in your pom for the templates to be included in your jar. Otherwise, that is if you expect your application to find the template on the file system, then you have to configure the `file.resource.loader.path` property. Does that make sense?

Comment: I created a simple maven project with one class file and one template in resources\templates folder of the same maven project. The project works fine in Eclipse IDE, its able to find vm file and process it. Now, export the project as jar with all dependencies.  The jar has everything class file and the template. Run the jar on command line using java -jar <jar_name>  and I get resource not found error. Hope this helps.

Comment: @NaiveCoder Does it work from the IDE if you remove the `file` resource loader?

Comment: I tried several combinations and it doesn't work. I have also debugged the velocity code, there is a loop through all resource loaders and it will try to find across all types of loader.